# How is date/time set on a Ubuntu Trusty?

Tags: time

I know`date`command and ntp protocol, but my question is related to default how date/time are set on boot (and/or checked/ajusted on an hypothetical automated schedule ...`cron`?).`ps ax|grep ntp`nor an overlook to`/etc/cron.*/`nor`/var/spool/cron/crontabs` showed me something evident. Please correct my grammar.

Comment: You're aware of the battery-powered system clock that most computers have, yes?

Comment: I am. I only said I know date & ntp to show I searched before posting so that I don't call for you to waste your time with silly questions. Unfortunately I failed for you as you could refrain throwing me the RTFM... but couldn't refrain to let me know you refrained. I didn't thought someone could think I don't know my stated`date`and`ntp` can help do the job when computer awakes  with dead RTC battery or drifting clock. Unfortunately too, I (and you) forgot`ntpdate``rdate`and above all`ntpdate-debian`, that's being stated only twice in the linked long post but seems the one that starts the job